# Is $\inf_{y\in A}\{(x-y)^2\}$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f:[0,1]\times[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined by $f(x,y)=(x-y)^2 $, and $A\subseteq [0,1]$.

Is the function $g:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$,  $g(x)=\inf_{y\in A}\{f(x,y)\}$ continuous?

At first I tried taking an open set $Y\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and showing that $g^{-1}(Y)$ is open, but with no luck. I also tried to fiddle around with $g$ in hope of finding some sort of inequality from which I can get an $\varepsilon-\delta$ proof. But at most I get some relationship that can't be used in that sense.

I thought about coming up with a counterexample, by finding an open set which does not map onto an open set, but from my guesses it seems they all do.

So I tried some simple cases with other functions and for example the functions $f(x,y)=x$ , which is trivial, or $f(x,y) = |x-y|$  that does have continuous $g$ but the proof for the second one does not translate well to this case.

Is there any general statement of the form : if $f$ satisfies some property on a bounded set $X$, and $A \subseteq X$ then $g$ is continuous?

Comment: $g(x)=(d(x,A))2$, The function $x\mapsto d(x,A)$ is continuous

Comment: @WHLin I think you meant $g(x)=0$, but what if $x\notin A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x_1 , x_2 \in [0, 1]$ and all $y \in A$ is
$$
 f(x_1, y) = f(x_2, y) + (x_2 - x_1)(2y-x_1-x_2) \ge g(x_2) - 2|x_2-x_1|
$$
which implies
$$
 g(x_1) \ge  g(x_2) - 2|x_2-x_1| \, .
$$
The same estimate holds with $x_1, x_2$ exchanged, so that
$$
 |g(x_1) - g(x_2) | \le 2|x_2-x_1| \, .
$$

This can be generalized to functions $f(x, y)$ which are uniformly equicontinuous in $y$, i.e. for each $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that
$$
 |f(x_1, y) - f(x_2, y)| < \epsilon
$$
for $|x_1 - x_2| < \delta$ and all $y \in X$.

This is for example satisfied if $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x, y)$ is uniformly bounded on $X \times X$.